# Calling custom method from within a Ruby core class

Tags: ruby, oop

TL;DR;
How can I call a method (written in the middle of nowhere) from within a Ruby core class?

---

I'm writing a script that manages text files. Here is my code:

```
File.open("file.txt", "w").each do |f|
  f.puts "Text to be inserted"
  f.puts text_generated
  f.puts "Some other text" if some_condition?
  f.puts ""
end
```

I want to clean up the code by introducing a method:

```
File.open("file.txt", "w").each do |f|
  f.puts_content(text_generated, some_condition?
  # -> Generates an error: private method called for <File> (NoMethodError)
end

def puts_content(text, cond)
  puts "Text to be inserted"
  puts text
  puts "Some other text" if cond
  puts ""
end
```

But in fact this method is not callable from within the `File` class because of private method access.

Can anyone explain that error, and how I can do that?

---

My workaround is to write those methods inside a custom `MyFile` class that inherits from `File`:

```
MyFile.open("file.txt", "w").each do |f|
  f.puts_content  # Seems to work
end

class MyFile < File
  def puts_content(cond)
    puts "Text to be inserted"
    puts text_generated_elsewhere
    puts "Some other text" if cond
    puts ""
  end
end
```

I could put that stuff directly in `File`, but I'm timid when it comes to touching a language core library.

I want to know if this is a good way to do it.

---

It is possible to call Ruby core methods from other core modules/classes. Does it mean that all the core modules/classes include or require one another? How does it work under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define a method on the top level, it is added an an instance method on Object and therefore accessible to descendent classes (most of the other core classes)

```
def foo
  1
end
method(:foo)
# => #<Method: Object#foo>
```

However the access level of this method seems to be different in IRB/pry than when running a script.

In IRB:

```
puts [].foo
# => 1
```

In a script:

```
puts [].foo
# => NoMethodError (private method called...)
```

Of course, you can always just call the private method using `send`:

```
[].send(:foo)
# or, in your case, f.send(:puts_content, text_generated, some_condition?)
```

Also, in neither case will it overwrite the method on the descendant class if it was already defined:

```
def length
  1
end
puts [].length
# => 0
```

Your second approach (patching the core class directly) will work and will overwrite the puts_content if it was already defined on File (which it wasn't). However if you want to avoid patching core classes, there are two approaches I recommend:

1. Use a static (class) method and pass the file object as an argument

   ```
   class FileUtils
     def self.puts_content(file, text, cond)
       file.puts "Text to be inserted"
       file.puts text
       file.puts "Some other text" if cond
       file.puts ""
     end
   end
   File.open("file.txt", "w").each do |f|
     FileUtils.puts_content(f, text_generated, some_condition?)
   end
   ```
2. use a refinement:

   ```
   module FileUtils
     refine File do
       def puts_content(text, cond)
         puts "Text to be inserted"
         puts text
         puts "Some other text" if cond
         puts ""
       end
     end
   end

   # elsewhere ...
   using FileUtils

   File.open("file.txt", "w").each do |f|
     f.puts_content(f, text_generated, some_condition?)
   end
   ```

   You can read about refinements [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html), but essentially, they're a way to patch a core class in a certain file or class only. This gives you the benefit of that nice, terse monkey-patched syntax with less risk of changing the behavior defined elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, I have never heard about Refinements, thank you *(Btw, [here is the documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html) for the last version (2.4.2) and Refinements is no more an experimental feature)*. But I really like your first suggestion. The overall structure stay exactly the same and the intent is not modified. I should learn a bit more about how all that stuff (static class) fit together. Also, how about using a module ? I've heard about module that it could be "mixed" with other classes and methods..

Comment: You can write the method in a module (it looks the same as the refinement definition, just without the `refine File do` line) and then include it with `File.include FileUtils`, however it is basically the same thing as re-opening the File class to add the method

Comment: Thank you. It's clear, Using a static class is still my favorite way. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

About your first question. You were getting the error because the method wasn't defined in the `File` class. So you were not able to call it like this `f.puts_content`.

You could define a method that receives the `File` as a parameter `puts_content(file, ...)`.

About the second part of your question, I this is a good solution (thinking object-oriented).

Comment: Hi, I don't thought about writing the file in that way..
In fact once I *open* the file I write many chunks of texts, and even by "packaging" them with some methods, I still have many custom methods.. 
So if I had to do that other way, I should open and close the file each time. But it could be simpler since it leaves low level stuff separate.
This lead to another question: Say I have to write 100 lines of text, is it preferable to open the file once and write all the lines or open and close the file 100 times, one for each write ? *(Supposing that I need to write 100 different lines)*

Comment: It is better to open the file once. Thinking about the code structure, it doesn't prevent you to split your code into many functions and classes.